# Get the title of a page/url

Tags: php, javascript

Using php or javascript I want to get the title of the page
Any help encouraged

Comment: What do you mean by "get the title"? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want like a user enters a url and it gives the title of the page

Comment: PHP is server-side. JavaScript is client-side. Your question suggests you don't have a firm grasp on how HTTP in general works.

Comment: I know what it means but I don't know in which language this can be done

Comment: darkporter is right - this isn't a language issue, it's an issue with your understanding of the language, especially considering you're talking about javascript and PHP - there isn't much choice.
Now, if instead you mentioned, say, ruby or python, I'd agree, but no, you're comparing between a client-side and a server-side language!

Comment: Omg when did I compared bw php and javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per marc's answer. you'll have to fetch your server side script to get the effect if using JavaScript

JavaScript: (this will only give you the title of your current page):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     alert(document.title);
     document.title='YOUR TITLE HERE';  //to set title
</script>
```

Here is the php way to do it:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$file = file_get_contents($url);

if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i",$file,$result)
print "The title of $url is <b>$result[1]</b>";
else
print "The page doesn't have a title tag";
```

this is modified from a post i bookmark long ago to achive the same effect [credit source](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-156022.html)

Comment: This is not I want, I want like a user enters a url and it gives the title of the page

Comment: @kritya in this case you'll have to use AJAX to submit the url the user enters if u were to use JavaScript, and then on the PHP side use the ajax url as `$url`

Comment: this will be helpful.. i was thinking if we have some http or server parameter that can give us the value... this is more like a hack .. thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Javascript. Javascript cannot fetch the contents of arbitrary links. It's a security issue  - look up XSR (cross-site requests) as to why.

You'd have to use AJAX to have your Javascript call a script on your server. That server-side script could fetch the specified page and parse out the title, then return it to the client-side Javascript.