# Set page's title based on another's URL title?

Tags: php, javascript

How do I set my title tag inner HTML to match the Title tag from an URL stored in the variable: $url?

I should somehow retrieve the Title on the url $url and then echo it inside my title tag.

How can I do this?

It's for this site, just in case you are curious:
http://www.linkimprov.com/home/

Thanks

Comment: Why add a [javascript] tag if you want to do the retrieval through PHP? =)

Comment: I thought it might be done with Ajax, but honestly I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This deals with the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205892/get-the-title-of-a-page-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$htm = file_get_contents($url);
$title = '';
if(preg_match('/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/',$htm,$match)){
    $title = $match[1];
}
echo $title;

//set the current page title to the retrieved title using js
echo '<script>document.title="' . addslashes($title) . '";</script>';
```

Comment: You should use a proper DOM parser, not a regular expression. Also, why wouldn't you just echo a title tag? It's `document.title`, by the way, if you insist on doing this with JavaScript.

Comment: Ow I missed it, thanks, that's document.title;, yeah echo $title will suffice, as for doing it in javascript I am just suggesting how to do it in JS. IMO, using DOM parser when just needing the title is overkill.

Comment: This is good though I echoed $title inside the title tag.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the URL (with [curl](http://www.php.net/book.curl) or what have you), parse the HTML, find the `title` tag, extract its text, and display it in your own web page.